# Button creates new sheet from template vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that is creating a new sheet and I can choose a name which is perfect. But I would need it to create a sheet from "TEMPLATE.xltx".

I have no idea how to do this, been testing different things but I cant get it to work. Anyone here that can help me with this issue?

```
Sub addWS()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

Do
    On Error Resume Next

    SheetName = InputBox("Skriv in namnet på den nya fliken" & vbNewLine & _
    "Inkludera inte dessa tecken !!" & vbNewLine & _
    "* [ \ / ' : ? [ ]", "Skapa ny flik")

    If SheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Create New Sheet at the end
     Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName



    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Set ANewSheet = ActiveSheet
        Exit Do
    End If

    MsgBox SheetName & " innehåller tecken som inte är okej." & vbNewLine & _
    "eller redan existerar!", vbCritical, "Check your Sheet Name"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
Call sourceSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: So instead of `.Add` -ing a worksheet, you want to `Copy` a worksheet from (an already open?) workbook called "Template.xlsm" ?

Comment: So is the sheet in question part of another file that is not open? What is the sheet name or index in TEMPLATE.xlsm?

Comment: I saved a workbook as template excel document. That is called TEMPLATE. I want this to work without the TEMPLATE workbook is open. Sorry, the name is calld "TEMPLATE.xltx"

Comment: Is there a reason for having a separate template file, could you not have the template sheet hidden in the current workbook and copy it from there when required?...I would change the current code, so that it checks that the sheet name is not in use and also check for any non suitable characters, before creating the new sheet.

Comment: Yeah, that would work aswell 5202456. But when I tried that, I got alot of questions if it would allow using all my "names" I created. And it did not work like I planned.

Would love if someone could take a look and change my code or something like that, so it would work better :(

Comment: We need to know what the template sheet contains? are there formulas, formatting, conditional formatting, drop down menus, data validation and so on.... if the template sheet is copied, then any cell references will point back to the original worksheet and not the one to where it has been pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is not tested and you need to adjust the file paths and sheet names to match the ones you actually have.
What the code is supposed to do is open the workbook that has the template sheet, copy it to your book, and then close the template.

```
    Sub addWS()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

    Set wbActive = ThisWorkbook

    TemplatePath = "C:\Template.xltx"
    set wbTemplate =  Application.Workbooks.Open(TemplatePath)
    set shtTemplate = wbTemplate.Sheets("TEMPLATE") 

    Do
        On Error Resume Next

        SheetName = InputBox("Skriv in namnet på den nya fliken" & vbNewLine & _
        "Inkludera inte dessa tecken !!" & vbNewLine & _
        "* [ \ / ' : ? [ ]", "Skapa ny flik")

        If SheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
        'Create New Sheet at the end
        wbTemplate.Worksheets(shtTemplate).Copy _     
        After:=wbActive.Sheets(wbActive.Sheets.count)
        wbActive.Sheets(wbActive.Sheets.count).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName

       wbTemplate.Close  false
       set wbTemplate = Nothing
       set shtTemplate = Nothing


        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set ANewSheet = ActiveSheet
            Exit Do
        End If

        MsgBox SheetName & " innehåller tecken som inte är okej." & vbNewLine & _
        "eller redan existerar!", vbCritical, "Check your Sheet Name"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot everyone! This code was the one Im looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim wb as WorkBook
Dim shNew as WorkSheet
Set wb = Activeworkbook
sTemplateFile = "C:\Template.xltx"

Set shNew = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count), Type:=sTemplateFile)
```

`sTemplateFile` should have only 1 sheet. And always check success because this operation fails sometimes.